# How do I iterate through an instance of this List class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, memory-management, data-structures, memory-leaks

I am trying to iterate over a list `var names = new List();` the following way:

```
var names = new List();
names.append('tom');
names.append('bob');
names.append('marshal');
names.append('Cartman');
names.append('Randy');

for(names.top(); names.currentPosition() < names.length(); names.next()) {
  console.log(names.getElement()); // going on and on stuck at one index! infinite loop!!!
}
```

> I am getting an infinite loop with an unchanging index of the list.  What
>   might be going wrong?

Assume the list has already been filled with values using an `append` method.  It is definitely not empty.  Here is the implementation of the List class:

```
function List() {
  this.dataStore = [];
  this.listSize = 0;
  this.position = 0;
}

List.prototype = {

  clear: function() {
    delete this.dataStore;
    this.dataStore = [];
    this.position = this.listSize = 0;
  },

  toString: function() {
    return this.dataStore.join(' \n');
  },

  getElement: function() {
    return this.dataStore[this.position];
  },

  append: function(el) {
    this.dataStore[this.listSize++] = el;
  },

  top: function() {
    this.position = 0;
  },

  bottom: function() {
    this.position = this.listSize - 1;
  },

  prev: function() {
    if(this.position > 0) {
      this.position--;
    }
  },

  next: function() {
    if(this.position < this.listSize - 1) {
      this.position++;
    }
  },

  length: function() {
    return this.listSize;
  },

  currentPosition: function() {
    return this.position;
  },

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `next()` function won't increment the `this.position` value past `this.listSize - 1` and therefore your conditional portion of the for loop will always evaluate to `true` since your `currentPosition()` will always be less than your `length()`.

Take for example, your `List` having 1 element in it. Here's the for loop values:

```
names.top() = 0
names.currentPosition() = 0
names.length() = 1
```

Calling `names.next()` checks `this.position < this.listSize - 1`. This can be rewritten: `0 < (1 - 1)`. So next doesn't increment `this.position` and your for loop runs infinitely.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  I have removed the `this.position < this.listSize - 1` constraint on the `next()` method.  Do you think this change might lead to unexpected behavior of the list elsewhere?  Say, when a user uses next() too many times and increments it beyond the size of the list.

Comment: @ng-hacker-319 Potentially. There's a lot of different options that you could do. One might be to design a separate class that works as an external iterator to your list, providing methods like `hasNext()` and `next()` and keeping its own position to where it currently is traversing the list. Another option is to have your `next()` function simply return the value in addition to incrementing the position and if you hit the end of the list, just return `null`. The only problem with returning `null` is your `List` won't be able to contain `null` as a valid value in it.